# Does "Wand" mean wall? [I think they call it a wand.]?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I m watching an American drama; it's called *Younger*. Ms. A is trying to hide her real age (40), and she's pretending she's 26 now. Her phone rang during a meeting. Ms. B is her colleague. Thanks.

> B: Come on, Oh, my God, what is happening? Give me that (phone)
>
> A: I have no idea. Somebody's been messing with my phone.
>
> B: Hmm. Looks like you have a date tonight with Josh. And Josh is
>   cute. Where is he taking you?
>
> A: Uh, no, I can't. Trout Pout has me buried with work.
>
> B: are you crazy? We re only in our 20s once.
>
> A: I know, you're right. It's true.
>
> B: Well, you got to live it.  Before you know it, you're gonna be in
>   your 40s, living in a house in the suburbs with a husband who watches
>   TV all night while you're in your bathtub, spritzing your shower hose
>   on our special place.
>
> A : **I think they call it a wand.**  [Sighs] Help me with my
>   makeup.
>
> B: Yes.

Comment: No. *wand* does not mean *wall*.   A dictionary should tell you what a wand is, but this is a joke full of sexual innuendo.  Try looking up *shower wand* in Google.

Comment: _Wand_ is the German term for 'wall'. But, I don't think that's what they were getting at.

Comment: To Sumelic, my Chinese subtitle showed a wall.. sigh.. That's why I wanted to find out the actual meaning instead of wall.

Comment: see mun Teh - please change your official selection from my pitiful "answer," to Mari-Lou A's unabashedly comprehensive offering.

Comment: Little Eva - I did it if you wished to. Thanks for your comment too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't let this pass by, the truth must be revealed.

A *wand* is also the name of a lady's sex toy. Perhaps unbeknownst to the OP, but some women masturbate in the shower using a detachable showerhead, (aka [handheld shower head](https://www.google.it/search?q=handheld%20shower%20heads&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=hGxQVaPAM6b8ygPYwoCQAw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=%22handheld%20shower%20heads%22)), by aiming (*“spritzing”*) the jet of warm/hot water ***“on on their special place”***.

Apparently, bathroom manufacturers [cottoned on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cotton-on)  and redesigned the ugly-looking shower head and made it more aesthetically pleasing and easier to hold.

[image]

The features of said shower  wand is as follows

> Choice of coverage or concentrated sprays
>   • Ergonomic design is comfortable and easy to grip
>   • KOHLER finishes resist corrosion and tarnishing, exceeding industry durability standards over two times
>   • MasterClean™ sprayface resists hard water buildup and is easy to clean

---

The fact that the model is the long-sounding name *Shower Wand Handshower* is, I'm sure, purely coincidental.
<sub>(All links are SFW)</sub>

Comment: I am _shocked_!

Comment: It's a shame Eva's feigned innocence and witticisms were deleted in the comment thread. They were delightful and very amusing to read.

Comment: Feigned? Feigned? Well I never! Plus-one, for your dedication to full transparency, your answer is far better than mine and far more deserving of the OP's adoption. You realize, of course, that you've opened a Pandora's box for see mun Teh. There's no closing that package. Ps: after reading your comment, I regret deleting that thread. I'll make it up to you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

**B**: spritzing your **shower hose** ...

**A**: I think they call it [shower hose] **a wand**

[image]

This is a picture of a shower "**wand**"

Comment: Ahh, sweet sweet innocent thing you :) I guess you've never needed a proper "wand" in your life....

Comment: I leave you with the honour of enlightening the OP as to its *proper* use. Because I fear the OP will still be in the dark.